Biblatex: write in any case the bibliographic reference in full at the foot of the page
I'm trying to personalize the visualization of the bibliografy using BibLatex and I'd like that all the refereces are fully written at the foot of the page and not abbreviated.
This is my bibliografy header
% Bibliography.
\usepackage[%
    style=musuos,
    citestyle=verbose-trad1,
    hyperref=true,
    backref=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\space-\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\space-\space}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\space}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

This is the result of the first citation:

this is the result of the second citation:

I'd like that each reference is like the first one but I could not find the way.
Is it possible?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your given code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing. And please add your used bib entry to the question!

In general, try with the citetracker=false option to the biblatex package. See the documentation, p. 65, http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf. In any case, yes, you should provide the MWEB, which allows us to see your .bib file (or refer to the biblatex-examples.bib file and input \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}). See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/236280
